# MVC 3 URL dynamic routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can you show me how to do that in MVC
I have 2 sites use the whole same Producing process, but some are different
Struct like:
domain.com
----Site1
----Site2
How can I setup the url like this
http://domain.com/Site1/controller1/action1
it will go to controller: site1_controller1 - action: action1

http://domain.com/Site2/controller1/action1
it will go to controller: site2_controller1 - action: action1

Or any good method can be used in this case.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using MVC areas instead of having a concatenated controller name. An area is just a group of controllers, so you could have an area called Site1 with a controller called controller1 inside it, and then a separate controller2 inside an area called Site2.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx for a walkthrough.

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to use Area.